# Init method for a singleton

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, singleton

I have my file `myAPI.swift`, and two objet `Round` and `GameStats`. My `Round` object also have an attribute `GameStats`. So what I want to do is to get the `GameStats` property that I store inside my users defaults then assign it inside my `Round` object.

```
class myAPI: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = myAPI()

    var currentStats: GameStats?
    var currentRound: Round?

    private init(){
       super.init()
       self.loadData()
       NSLog("Stats have been reload: \(self.currentRound?.gameStats)") // Return nil
       // If I try to add this line the app stop running and nothing happens
       NSLog("Test Singleton: \(myApp.sharedInstance.currentRound?.gameStats)")
    } 

     func loadData(){
            let backupNSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("backupNSData")
            if let backupNSData = backupNSData as? NSData{
                let backupData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(backupNSData)
                if let backupData = backupData as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    guard let round = backupData["currentRound"] as? Round else {
                        print("error round loaddata")
                        return
                    }
                    self.currentRound = round
                    guard let stats = backupData["stats"]  as? GameStats else {
                        print("error guard stats")
                        return
                    }
                    self.currentRound.gameStats = stats
                   NSLog("Stats reloaded: \(stats)") // This is not nil it works here
                 }
          }
    }
```

When my app crash I call this function to save the data

```
func backupData(){
        var backupData:[String:AnyObject] = [String:AnyObject]()
        if let round = self.currentRound {
            backupData["currentRound"] = round
            ColorLog.purple("Stats saved inside Round \(round.gameStats)")
        }
        if let stats = self.currentStat {
            backupData["stats"] = stats
            ColorLog.purple("Stats saved : \(stats)")
        }
        let backupNSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(backupData)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(backupNSData, forKey: "backupNSData")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }
```

So I have two question,

1. Is it normal that I can't call my singleton like `myApp.sharedInstance.currentRound.id = 5` (for instance) inside the `init()` (I guess it is but I didn't find anything about that)
2. Why in my `init()` method my first `NSLog` `self.currentRound?.gameStats` is nil when in the function `loadData()` it wasn't ? It seems like it's losing its reference since we are leaving the function.

What am I doing right now is adding a `currentStats` property in my singleton, then when I retrieve data instead of doing `self.currentRound.gameStats = stats` I do `self.currentStats = stats`,  then `self.currentRoud.gameStats = self.currentStats` and If I do that it works, I don't really know If I am doing the things right here.

Also my two objects `Round` and `GameStats` conform to `NSCoding` protocol as I implemented  `@objc func encodeWithCoder` and `@objc required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` methods for both of them.

Thank for you help.

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2

Comment: "Is it normal that I can't call my singleton like ... inside the `init`?" - There's some circular logic with that construct: Remember, `init` is called when the `sharedInstance`, itself, is being initialized. I could imagine synchronization deadlock or simple infinite recursion. Looking at stack, it looks like deadlock. (BTW, I assume you meant `MyAPI.sharedInstance...`, not `MyApp.sharedInstance...`.)

Comment: Minor unrelated observation: You might consider adopting Cocoa naming conventions, where types (classes and structs) always begin with uppercase letter. So, I'd suggest `MyAPI` (or, better, something that describes the nature of the API, e.g. `GameAPI` or what have you).